# how to access min of hash value[2] in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I access the min or max of particular column of values in a Hash in Ruby

I have a hash with array of values for key. I would like to get min or max value in a particular column of array values so that I can change the value of first column. Below is my code. Any suggestions?

`lru_c()`
when I run this code, I am getting 0, i.e. the least of the values of third hash. what I need is least of the values of column 2 of the array values. i.e. `[6,2,9,4].min` . I want to access `h[2]` which has min value in the last column.

```rb
def lru_c()
    h = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }

    h[1] = [0,0,6]
    h[2] = [0,0,2]
    h[3] = [0,0,9]
    h[4] = [7,1,4]

    puts h.values[2].min
end
```

Comment: @Amadan oh, indeed. `h.min_by { |_, v| v.last }` of course, thanks!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution.  Somehow, this did not work properly for me. Maybe I did not put across my problem properly. Anyhow, thanks again

Comment: Can you explain why the solution from @AlekseiMatiushkin does't work for you? You can use it as `h[h.min_by{|_,v| v.last}.first][0] = :whatever`, so `h #=> {1=>[0, 0, 6], 2=>[:whatever, 0, 2], 3=>[0, 0, 9], 4=>[7, 1, 4]}`

Comment: Raj, it's unclear whether the answer you're seeking is `2` because that's the minimum of column 2 of all the values, `2` because that's the key for the hash entry that contains the minimum value in column 2 of all the values, or `h[2]` which is the value array which contains the minimum value in column 2 of all the values.  Could you please clarify by explicitly stating what the return value should be, using an example where there's no ambiguity between keys, values, and value indices?

Answer (score 2):

[`collect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) will iterate through any enumerable, such as a hash, to create an array containing the values specified by the block argument.  Since it yields an array, you can then apply `.min`:

```
h.collect { |_, value| value[2] }.min
```

The enumerator for a hash coughs up both the keys and the values, but since the keys aren't needed in your specification I've used an `_` placeholder.

If there's any chance some of the values won't have a `[2]` index, you should change `.min` to `.compact.min`.

Comment: This does not return the expected result (`h[2]` _array_) though.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin My reading of Raj's question was that 1) the array he was looking for was composed of the elements of column 2 from each hash value; and 2) he wanted only the `min` value at the end, the array was not intrinsically of interest.  If you want to preserve the array for some reason, assign it to a variable and then apply the `min`.

Answer (score 1):

well i am not an expert but i would choose dynamic solution like below

```
def fetch_value_of(hash, col, min_max)
  hash.map{|_key, values| values[col]}.send("#{min_max}")
end
```

pass your hash , column for which you want to have mix/max value and which value you want , minimum or the maximum.

for eg:

```
fetch_value_of(h, 2, 'max')
```

Comment: `send`?! What for?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution.  I needed a single liner without having to write another method.  Anyhow, thanks again

Comment: then you can also convert this method to single line , i just made it separate because i more like modular and dynamic way then linear way, although you can define variable and make linear way also dynamic.

Comment: **send** is the method in which you can pass method name  for calling method dynamically . in simple way **dynamic method calling**

Comment: I know what `send` does, thanks. It just looks weird here, because you might a) use `public_send` which is _always_ preferred and b) you don’t need to interpolate a parameter, `public_send(min_max)` would perfectly work.

Comment: first point i didn't know so thanks for sharing it, and yes second one its works fine without interpolation. thanks @AlekseiMatiushkin